# Cannot upgrade anything in vps install (migrated wp)

Tags: updates

I get this error in my wordpress_http_error.log

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php(95): request_filesystem_credentials('update.php?acti...', 'ftpext', false, '/var/www/h$
#1 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php(196): WP_Upgrader_Skin->request_filesystem_credentials(false, '/var/www/html/w...', false)
#2 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php(691): WP_Upgrader->fs_connect(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-plugin-upgrader.php(186): WP_Upgrader->run(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/wp-admin/update.php(65): Plugin_Upgrader->upgrade('cont
```

And I can't update wp/plugins. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Update process tries to get wp_filesystem credentials and cannot do it.

It seems that file privileges are wrong. Files must have 644 mode, directories - 755. Owner of files and directories must be the same user, on whose behalf is running php.

Php user is set in www.conf file.